# Kaltura's All IN ONE Video plugin for Wordpress: is there any "how to use" documentation?

Tags: wordpress, video-streaming, video-capture, kaltura

Kaltura's plugin for Wordpress looks like a great tool.  It seems to work to add video to a page while editing the page.  But, the video doesn't display once you view the site.  Also, there is a button on the post page that says "Add Video Comment".  It doesn't work either.  This is what I'd REEEEEEally like to get working.

I've been to the Kaltura site, and there is reams and reams of documentation, but nothing that actually applies to this Wordpress plugin.  Its almost like it doesn't exist to them....

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a faulty installation... the features you mentioned should just work after installation.

- Are you using Kaltura.com or your own self hosted Kaltura CE?
- Any public URL where we can see the issues?

Comment: Im using the hosted Kaltura.  I reinstalled and the same issue remains.  Looks like it should work, but nothing happens.  Do I have to do any additional setup on Kaltura after the installation?  Maybe that's it.  IF so, there's nothing about this in the setup documentation, what there is of it....